# Android - keep variable's value in main activity

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

I'd like to know if there's any solution to keep variables value in memory when I go to another activity and then back to main activity (main activity wasn't killed - onCreate(Bundle) parameter is null). In my case variable is ArrayList.

I've solved this problem by declaring variable as static. This solution is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14604485/3195752.

It works, but I don't like it. Each instance of class should have own variable (list). I know I'll have only one instance of activity but still it's doesn't seem right.

Thank you for your answers!

**EDIT #1**
Adding some code for [atxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621264/atxe)

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_floorplan_icon_green"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Lightgreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.RoomArrange"
            android:label="@string/activity_room_arrange"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Lightgreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.FloorPlan"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_floor_plan"
            android:parentActivityName="com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.RoomArrange"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Lightgreen">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="RoomArrange" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

*activity_room_arrange.xml*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.RoomArrange"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        />
    <!-- The left floor plan drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/left_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/d_green"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/action_bar_color"/>
    <!-- The right add equipment drawer -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/right_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/d_green"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/action_bar_color"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*RoomArrange.java* - I tried to delete all lines that doesn't affect activity change

```
    public class RoomArrange extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String PLAN_NAME_MESSAGE = "com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.PLAN_NAME_MESSAGE";
    private final static String PLAN_LIST_BUNDLE_ID = "com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.PLAN_LIST_BUNDLE_ID";

    private static ArrayList<String> mFloorPlanList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private DrawerLayout mLeftDrawerLayout;
    private DrawerLayout mRightDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mLeftDrawerList;
    private LinearLayout mRightDrawerItems;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mLeftDrawerToggle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mRightDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_arrange);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Fill list when its empty - application start
        if(mFloorPlanList.size() == 0)
        {
            List<String> tmpList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.floorplans_array));
            mFloorPlanList.addAll(tmpList);
            mFloorPlanList.add(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_add_new_plan));
        }

        mLeftDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mLeftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mRightDrawerItems = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mLeftDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mFloorPlanList));

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            //selectItem(0);
        }
        else
        {
            mFloorPlanList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(PLAN_LIST_BUNDLE_ID);
            mLeftDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mFloorPlanList));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mLeftDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            closeRightDrawer();
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.action_arrange_add:
                onAddActionSelected();
                return true;

                //......

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Click for swapping floor plans
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
    {
        bundle.putStringArrayList(PLAN_LIST_BUNDLE_ID, mFloorPlanList);
        bundle.putInt("a", 25);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    /** Swaps floor plans, create new or edit */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Create new floor plan
        if(position == mFloorPlanList.size() - 1)
        {
            // TODO Create new floor plan
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_add_new_plan));
            alert.setMessage("Add name of a plan");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(input);

            final RoomArrange activity = this;

            alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.button_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String value = input.getText().toString();

                    mFloorPlanList.add(mFloorPlanList.size() - 1, value);

                    // Call floor plan activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FloorPlan.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PLAN_NAME_MESSAGE, value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.button_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

*activity_floor_plan.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nuduoz.batchelorwork.uiprototype2.FloorPlan">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*FloorPlan.java*

```
public class FloorPlan extends ActionBarActivity {

        public final static String PLAN_NAME = "New floor plan";

        private String planName;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_floor_plan);

            Bundle extras;
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if(extras == null) {
                    planName= getResources().getString(R.string.plan_default_name);
                } else {
                    planName= extras.getString(RoomArrange.PLAN_NAME_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                planName= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(RoomArrange.PLAN_NAME_MESSAGE);
            }

            getActionBar().setTitle(planName);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.floor_plan, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I really don't know where problem is.. :(
ad: I know I could have some problems in my code so feel free to point out them.

Comment: I donot see actually any problem using static variable. why do you thing that is is not good.

Comment: It works, but like I said static variable should be constant across all instances of the class. In my case it's a list of items which dynamicaly changes in runtime and each instance could have different items in this list. I know that Activity class will have only one instance but this "static" solution doesn't seem right for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use internal data to store the data. See here for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

This works relatively well, and is persistent through restarts, but it is a pain to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the variable as static you do not have the warranty that the variable value will remain there on resuming that activity. The OS might kill your activity if running out of memory.

As commented in another answer, saving that information into a data store (file system, shared preferences, sqlite,...) is an option. But, in my opinion is not the most clean way. I prefer to recreate the activity (and its state) as Android documentation suggests: using `onSaveInstanceState()` to store the data you want on the recreation and then retrieving it in `onCreate()` (from the bundle) or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Check the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: A spend lot of time on this solution, but it doesn't work in case you go from main activity to another activity and then go back (up/home in actionBar). I get null as parameter in `onCreate()`. I think that main activity just haven't been destroyed.

Comment: If your activity is not killed, then that variable remains as it was. Isn't it? The recreation of the activity happens if it was killed, that can (potentially) happen when you navigate further to other activities.

Comment: I think I'm missing something in my app. `onCreate()` is called everytime I navigate to another activity and then back. And everytime there 's `null` as parameter and all variables at it's initial state.

Comment: Is `onCreate()` called when you go back to that activity? Usually it should not, but it could be the case if that activity is killed. Did you saved anything in `onSaveInstanceState()` via `bundle.put...`?

Comment: Yes I did. `onSaveInstanceState()` was called, and after `bundle.put..` values were inserted in it. But when I hit up in actionBar in another activity, main activity's `onCreate()` is called everytime. Second activity with up button in actionBar is default activity with parent atribute defined.

Comment: I would need to see some code, and know your app navigation architecture to say something else :P

Comment: Ok I'll try to add it into question. But it takes me about 2-3 hours to get home.

Comment: No prob. I will answer whenever possible as well ;-)

Comment: Ok I added everything what could cause my problem.. Thank you a lot for your assistance :)